# File Encrypted using Kleopetra, started showing error while decrypting?

Tags: gnupg

I encrypted one of my text files with *Kleopatra*, which I have been using for 4 months. It was working fine, but since two weeks I'm getting an error when decrypting the file:

```
Can not connect to GnuPG user Interface (Kleopatra) IPC connect call failed.
```

Please help.

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory: *"Can not connect to GnuPG user Interface"*. Are you sure GnuPG IPC is up?

Answer (score 2):

I've been seeing the same issue today. I tried to encrypt in the file menu and that completed successfully. But if I encrypt a file by right mouse menu, then it failed again.

The problem was resolved after I **shutdown and re-start GnuPG.**

BTW, before I get the problem, I encrypted a large file (more than 1 GB). I am not sure if the two are related.